# playing sound file iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, nsdocumentdirectory

I am playing a sound file in `viewDidLoad` method. The sound file is saved in document directory. It is successfully played when the view loaded first time. But when I pop this view and come back then it is not played.

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *localFilePathSound =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound.caf"]]];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localFilePathSound]) {
        //NSString *clapPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scaryVoice" ofType:@"wav"];
        CFURLRef clapURL = (CFURLRef ) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePathSound];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (clapURL, &clappingFileId);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clappingFileId);
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    else{
        NSString *clapPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scaryVoice" ofType:@"wav"];
        CFURLRef clapURL = (CFURLRef ) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:clapPath];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (clapURL, &clappingFileId);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clappingFileId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to play this method after coming back from a view.
Just write the above code in the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` **or** `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *localFilePathSound =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound.caf"]]];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localFilePathSound])
    {
        //NSString *clapPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scaryVoice" ofType:@"wav"];
        CFURLRef clapURL = (CFURLRef ) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePathSound];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (clapURL, &clappingFileId);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clappingFileId);
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    else
    {
        NSString *clapPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scaryVoice" ofType:@"wav"];
        CFURLRef clapURL = (CFURLRef ) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:clapPath];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (clapURL, &clappingFileId);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clappingFileId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewDidLoad` method is only being called the first time the view appears.  To make something happen every time the view appears, put your code in `viewWillAppear:`.

Be sure to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` from your method.